# Is it possible to check the syntax of S-expressions in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

I wrote a file of S-expressions. I would like to check if there is some syntax error (i.e. some obvious mismatching between parentheses). Emacs has S-mode, but I don't know if Emacs can check that? Thanks.

Comment: Cool, didn't know about check-parens.  My answer would be to write a bit of elisp to call (read) in a loop.

Comment: @phils: thanks. that will show unmatched right parenthesis. But the unmatching can be due to left parenthesis mis-placed or missing. In that case, how can we find which left parenthesis or its position is the culprit?

Comment: You can't. `check-parens` can't know whether there's a missing opening parenthesis, or a redundant closing one. To the parser, both case look the same, and it'd need additional context to figure out.